# Is it better to use HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled or #if DEBUG?

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a code that should run only in debug mode.

Is it better to use HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled or "#if DEBUG ... #endif"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the debug code should absolutely not be compiled into your release assemblies, then it's better to use `#if` style (or consider using [conditional methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28VS.71%29.aspx)).

When using `#if DEBUG` blocks (or conditional methods), the code will not be compiled into your assembly if the build is not a `Debug` build i.e. the `DEBUG` compilation symbol is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

Those are 2 completely different things!

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

is related to the current **web.config** setting

```
debug=true
```

where

```
#if DEBUG ... #endif
```

is related to the project **configuration debug/release setting** at build time

Be carefull!

Answer (score 1):

The pre-processor directive (`#if DEBUG ...`) has the advantage that the debugging code will not make it into the production environment, so there is zero possibility of it being executed (assuming you have effective configuration management procedures!)